# Error while working with Ebay API

Tags: python, ebay-api

I'm trying to access the Ebay API by using the ebaysdk module. I'm using the example code given in the documentation and have registered on Ebay Developer's site to generate the required App ID. Here's the source code of my program:

ebaay.py

```
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection as Finding

api = Finding(appid="123456789")
response = api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', {'keywords': 'Python'})
print(response.dict())
```

YAML file (assuming my app id is 123456789)

```
# eBay SDK Defaults
name: ebay_api_config
# Trading API Sandbox - https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/products/trading-api
api.sandbox.ebay.com:
compatability: 719
appid: 123456789
certid: ENTER_YOUR_CERTID_HERE
devid: ENTER_YOUR_DEVID_HERE
token: ENTER_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE

# Trading API - https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/products/trading-api
api.ebay.com:
version: 719
appid: 123456789
certid: ENTER_YOUR_CERTID_HERE
devid: ENTER_YOUR_DEVID_HERE
token: ENTER_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE

# Finding API - https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/products/finding-api
svcs.ebay.com:
appid: 123456789
version: 1.0.0

# Shopping API - https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/products/shopping-api
open.api.ebay.com:
appid: 123456789
version: 671
# Optional affiliate tracking
# http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/Concepts/ShoppingAPI_FormatOverview.html#StandardURLParameters
trackingid: ENTER_YOUR_TRACKINGID_HERE
trackingpartnercode: ENTER_YOUR_PARTNERCODE_HERE
```

However, when I try to run my Python script, I encounter the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python27/Web Scraping/ebaay.py", line 3, in <module>
    api = Finding(appid="123456789")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ebaysdk\finding\__init__.py", line 70, in __init__
    config_file=kwargs.get('config_file', 'ebay.yaml'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ebaysdk\config.py", line 39, in __init__
    self._populate_yaml_defaults()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ebaysdk\config.py", line 50, in _populate_yaml_defaults
    for k, val in dataobj.get(self.domain, {}).items():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

What seems to be wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indent each API field:

```
# eBay SDK Defaults
name: ebay_api_config
# Trading API Sandbox - https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/products/trading-api
api.sandbox.ebay.com:
    compatability: 719
    appid: 123456789
    certid: ENTER_YOUR_CERTID_HERE
    devid: ENTER_YOUR_DEVID_HERE
    token: ENTER_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE

# Trading API - https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/products/trading-api
api.ebay.com:
    version: 719
    appid: 123456789
    certid: ENTER_YOUR_CERTID_HERE
    devid: ENTER_YOUR_DEVID_HERE
    token: ENTER_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE

# Finding API - /developers/ebay/products/finding-api
svcs.ebay.com:
    appid: 123456789
    version: 1.0.0

# Shopping API - /developers/ebay/products/shopping-api
open.api.ebay.com:
    appid: 123456789
    version: 671
```

Also, its not necessary put the appid in your `Finding()` call in ebaay.py if you have it in the ebay.yaml file. `api = Finding()` will work.